# How to persist Mobx-state-tree data on NextJS

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to use `Mobx-state-tree` with `NextJS` like in this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mobx-state-tree-typescript).

**Problem**

After user login user details are saved in mobx state. but after page refresh those data are gone. I want to persist data on mobx state so the user data are stay on mobx state until user logout. I cant use `localStorage` to persist data because of the `ssr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mst-persist](https://github.com/agilgur5/mst-persist) to persist your state in MobX-State-Tree. For SSR issue, you have to call persist function conditionally with "typeof window !== undefined" checking.

So your code should be look something like this,

`if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { persist(...) }`